仮想マシンで SQL Server 2022 のインストーラーを実行するとエラーが発生する
実現したいこと
SQL Server 2022のインストーラーを実行してsqlserverをインストールしたい
実行環境
仮想マシン:Hyper-Vでserver用のマシンを作成
OS：Windows Server 2019
ローカルPC OS：Windows 11 Home
メモリ：4096MB
ディスク：40GB
ネットワークアダプター：内部（internal）
ファイアウォール：無効
インストーラー：ローカルPCに一度インストールし仮想環境にインストーラーファイルをコピーしています。
発生エラーについて

インストールしたサイトURL
：
https://www.microsoft.com/ja-jp/evalcenter/download-sql-server-2022
インストーラーを実行した際にエラーが発生しました。
解決するためにマイクロソフトの公式サイトや質問回答などを見ましたが何をしたら解決できるのか分からなかったためこちらで質問させていただきます。
よろしくお願いいたします。

インストーラーを実行した仮想マシンの時刻が大幅にずれていたりしませんか？

仮想マシンの環境はインターネットに接続できますか？仮想マシン上のブラウザーでMicrosoftのホームページは閲覧できますか？

sayuriさん　回答していただきありがとうございます。インストーラーを実行したserver用の仮想マシンの時刻を確認しましたが、携帯、ローカルのPCの時刻と同じ時刻が仮想マシンに表示されていました。

raccyさん回答していただきありがとうございます。ネットワークアダプタをinternalに設定しているためインターネットに接続できないです。仮想マシン上でMicrosoft
のホームページは閲覧できない状態です。

cubickさん見やすい・伝わりやすいように編集していただきありがとうございます。

https://www.microsoft.com/ja-jp/evalcenter/download-sql-server-2022
上記サイトからダウンロードできる SQL2022-SSEI-Eval.exe はインストールを実行するときにインターネット環境が必要です。インターネットに接続できない環境で実行しても、インストールはできません。
インターネットに接続できるようにするのが一番お手軽なのですが、どうしてもインターネットに接続したくないという場合は、インストールするファイル一式が入ったメディアを入手するという方法があります。次の方法を試してみてください。

インターネットに接続できるローカルPCでインストーラー SQL2022-SSEI-Eval.exe を実行します。
インストールの種類で「メディアのダウンロード」を選びます。
ISOまたはCABを選択して、ダウンロードします。
ダウンロードが終わった後、

ISOの場合は、ダウンロードされたISOを仮想マシンでマウントします。
CABの場合は、ダウンロードされたSQLServer2022-x64-JPN.boxとSQLServer2022-x64-JPN.exeを仮想マシン内にコピーします。


仮想マシン上で、マウントされたメディア内のsetup.exe、または、コピーしたSQLServer2022-x64-JPN.exeを実行します。

これで、インターネットに接続できない仮想マシンであってもSQLServerがインストールできるはずです。

raccyさん　回答していただきありがとうございます。返信が遅くなり申し訳ございません。インターネットに接続する方法と接続しずにメディアを入手するという２通りの方法を教えていただきましてありがとうございます。　　　　　　　今回はインターネットに接続しない方法でメディアからisoをマウントする方法を試してみることにしました。ローカルのPCでインストーラーをインターネットにつながっている状態で実行しメディアを選択したところ下記のようなエラーが出てしまいました。　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　アクティビティ mediaDouwnloadActivityの実行に失敗しました。　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　sqlインストーラーファイル“sqlserver2022-x64-JPN.iso”をダウンロードできませんでした。状態’serverProtocolViolation’　説明：サーバーによってプロトコル違反が発生しました。section=ResponseStatusLineよろしくお願いいたします。

インターネットに接続できるのにメディアをダウンロードできないとなると、「PCの何かが壊れている」「企業・学校のPCなので制限がかかっている」「企業・学校のネットワークなので制限がかかっている」「プロキシが壊れているか対応していない」等が考えられますが、原因を追及し、解決することは簡単ではありません。他にPCやインターネット接続環境があれば、そちらの環境でダウンロードを試してみることをお勧めします。私の力ではこれ以上助けることは難しいです。

raccyさん ありがとうございます。自宅のpcです。プロキシが壊れてしまっているかもしれないということですね。今回は仮想マシンのネットワークアダプタを変更してインターネットに接続してSQLをインストールすることにします。複数日に渡って回答していただきありがとうございます。

遅くなり申し訳ございません。インターネットに接続して再度インストールし直したところISOファイルを無事インストールできました。raccyさん、sayuriさんありがとうございました。
